# Matlab gui for selecting a text file and the utilize it in further code

Tags: function, matlab, user-interface, callback

I have spent a long time studying about the gui. I have made the blank template containing all the buttons and input editable text box. but am facing problem with callback functions.

I have written a code which requires manually entering the text file containing data into the script file and then input a variable's value (in this case 'b') which is then utilized in the later part of the code. i wanted to make the program more user friendly so that one can select the text file from any directory by pushing a button and can change the value of b in a box provided. Also I have not included any functions in the main code...so its a basic data fitting code.

I tried studying about gui in matlab and other resources but am not able to understand it and use it. Therefore i cant put any of my work done uptill now.  Please help me in solving the problem..

Comment: Have a look at Matlab Guide. (http://www.mathworks.se/discovery/matlab-gui.html) 
You have to do some tutorials to learn basic gui-programming, then your question will be quite simple.

Comment: @EirikO can I make the entire gui interactively with the GUIDE ?

Comment: You can build the gui (drag-and-drop) and you will get a framework for the logical part of the programming, with useful comments.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a button in your GUI and include the following code in the associated callback function:

```
[aux_file,aux_path]=uigetfile();
if ~isempty('aux_file')
  handles.data.file_name = fullfile(aux_path,aux_file);
  handles.data.file_data = load(handles.data.file_name);
  guidata(handles.figure_window, handles);
end
```

Now, you can use the data in other functions.